Understanding Conducted emission test setup
Why is the main conducted emission setup separated by 0.8 meters from any metal surface and also from ground plane?

(Image source: Electromagnetic Compatibility (EMC) course offered for Msc. Electronics in Syddansk Universitet (SDU))

How can be the height of the box (high side) AAN at 0.80 m if the height of this box (low side) to the ground plane is already at 0.80 m?

I too thought of that, but the AAN should be around 10 cms, which alters the distance to 0.7 m. I guess that must also be standardized.

It prevents capacitive coupling from your device/wiring to the ground plane.  More accurately, it minimizes it and standardizes it.
Put in other words, it ensures that all currents in the cabling are going through your probe, rather than bypassing the probe by taking the capacitive route through the ground plane.

I wouldn't say "minimizes", but reduces, perhaps; but "standardizes", most importantly of all, in a setup typical of office use (equipment on a wood/plastic table, etc.). It also keeps cables and enclosures away from the ground plane, increasing impedance, and likely, coupling factor to near and far (radiating) field.

btw what effect does it have with the parasitic inductance? since it is separated by 0.8 meters, won't there be a lot of inductances? and since we want to measure conducted emission of high frequency current harmonics, having ah esl doesn't it increase the impedance curve for higher frequencies?

@Fredrick, sure, there's some effect on impedances. the important part is that it is standardized and, more or less, mimics what a user might do with their equipment.  Finally, your current probe is measuring the current, largely irrespective of impedance.  So you're measuring the current, whether you set up your loop to have more or less inductance.   That's part of the reason for the LISN, to further Stabilize (and better yet, standardize) the impedances the device will see and thus make the measurement more repeatable.
